# How to tell if MKLocalSearch returns an exact or approximate location

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have run into an issue using MKLocalSearch where I am not able to tell if the result given back by MKLocalSearch is an approximate location or an exact location.

For example:

Feeding "500 3rd st, San Francisco, CA, 94107 to MKLocalSearch will return the exact coordinate for the address since that is an accurate address.

Feeding a slightly off address such as "500 3rd st, San Francisco, CA, 94103", notice the zip code is wrong, returns a result with a coordinate matching the address, the coordinate is an approximate location and not the actual location.  It is off by a few blocks.

The problem is that the user might think that the address was correctly entered and the coordinate provided is the exact location.

Is there a way to distinguish between a result that is approximate and a result that is exact?

Below are the results spit out for the two above queries:

Accurate Address:

```
<MKLocalSearchResponse: 0x7faf9abea2a0> {
boundingRegion = "<center:+37.78081461, -122.39579073 span:+0.00068973, +0.00086888>";
mapItems =     (
    "<MKMapItem: 0x7faf97ae9aa0> {\n    isCurrentLocation = 0;\n    name = \"500 3rd St\";\n    placemark = \"500 3rd St, 500 3rd St, San Francisco, CA  94107, United States @ <+37.78081460,-122.39579056> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+37.78081461,-122.39579074> radius 54.08', center:<+37.78081461,-122.39579074>, radius:54.08m)\";\n}"
);
}
```

Wrong zip:

```
<MKLocalSearchResponse: 0x7faf97f3d560> {
    boundingRegion = "<center:+37.78398120, -122.39890034 span:+0.00317604, +0.00401865>";
    mapItems =     (
        "<MKMapItem: 0x7faf939ba240> {\n    isCurrentLocation = 0;\n    name = \"500 3rd St\";\n    placemark = \"500 3rd St, 500 3rd St, San Francisco, CA  94103, United States @ <+37.78398120,-122.39890030> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+37.78398120,-122.39890034> radius 249.57', center:<+37.78398120,-122.39890034>, radius:249.57m)\";\n}"
    );
}
```